# Regular expression to validate time

Tags: regex

I have tried many combination of

```
\d{1,2}:\d{2}
```

to validate a period of time(ie: 0:33 or 12:33).

Therefore, for the most part the above expression works, but I also need to 
1) validate ":33" and 
2) invalidate "00:33a"

I have googled around and try to combine \s* but it still does not satisfy both conditions.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Vulcan, `99:99` would be valid, not sure if OP would want that as valid.

Comment: @zzzzBov To invalidate 99:99, the following should work: `^([0-2]?\d)?:[0-5]\d$`

Comment: Oops, should be `[01]` in that first clause.

Comment: `^(?:1[0-2]|\d)?:[0-5]\d$` is probably what OP's looking for, but that assumes the language is something like JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match only valid times (e.g. 23:59, but not 25:03 etc), you could try the following regular expression:

```
^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5]?[0-9]$
```

Comment: This is good but assumes a single digit for hour (3:.. instead of 03:..).  If a two digit hour is needed I think it would be `^([0-1][0-9]|...`

Comment: MrBlue, that's not entirely correct. The [01]? part allows for both having no preceding zero (3:...) and a preceding zero (03:...) (and also having a preceding one (13:...).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to specify the beginning ^ and end $ string signifiers

```
^\d{1,2}:\d{2}$
```

That way 00:33a will invalidate

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question more closely and expanding on Gijs's answer, this may be what you're after...

```
^(?:[0-9]?|(?:[0-1][0-9])?|(?:2[0-3])?):[0-5][0-9]$
```

Allows for ':mm', 'h:mm' or 'hh:mm'.

I'm not sure how universal the (?: non-capturing group is - I'm accustomed to it from .Net.